# Can't reach max tcp connections for single server

Tags: node.js, linux, sockets, tcp, centos7

I'm testing max tcp connections in CentOS7. I changed open files limit to 1000000(ulimit -n 1000000) and edited `sysctl.conf` as shown below. Then I test with node.js as follow code (single server):

```
var net = require('net');
var count = 0
//server
let server = net.createServer(function(conn){
    conn.on("close", function(code, reason){
        console.log("close", code, reason);
    })
    conn.on("error", function(code, reason){
        console.log("error close", code, reason);
    })
}).listen({port : 8080, host: "0.0.0.0", backlog: 100000}).on("connection", _=>{count++});

//client
setInterval(_=>{new Array(300).fill(1).map((_,index)=>index+1926).map(p=>{
    new net.Socket().connect(8080,'127.0.0.1')
        .on('error',function(e){
            console.log(count);
            console.log(e);
            process.exit()}
        );
    })&&console.log('connection count:',count)},10)
```

Results:

```
connection count: 64200
connection count: 64500
64500
{ Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1:8080 - Local (127.0.0.1:0)
    at internalConnect (net.js:872:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (net.js:962:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080 }
```

It throw EADDRNOTAVAIL while connection count reach 64500.
then I tried multiple server as follows:

```
var net = require('net');
var count = 0
//server
new Array(300).fill(1).map((_,index)=>index+1926).map(p=>{
    net.createServer().listen(p).on('connection',_=>count++)
    })

//client
setInterval(_=>{new Array(300).fill(1).map((_,index)=>index+1926).map(p=>{
    new net.Socket().connect(p,'127.0.0.1')
        .on('error',function(e){
            console.log(e);
            process.exit();
        })})&&console.log('connection count:',count);},10)
```

Results:

```
connection count: 392400
connection count: 392700
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why multiple server connections can over 390000 but single server connections can only reach 64500 and throw EADDRNOTAVAIL error?

---

`/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 1200

net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 5000

fs.file-max = 1000000

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range= 1024 65535

net.core.somaxconn = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't binding your outbound connection sockets. This causes the operating system to assign them a local source IP address and port. Likely it's using the same local source IP address (127.0.0.1) for all of them and thus only has around 65,000 ports. Bind it yourself to a random combination of local IP address inside the loopback range and port inside the unprivileged range. If you get `EADDRNOTAVAIL`, try a different random combination.

Comment: But multiple server version is still using the same local source IP address for all of them, why it can connect over 65000?

Comment: If you bind a socket to a local IP address, can you still connect remote IPs with it?

Comment: @GapMAX It can distinguish the connections by the server they're connected to.

Comment: @peterh No. If you only have a single source IP address that you can use to talk to a single remote server listening on a single port, you can't have more than 65,000 or so connections to it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Afaik you are right. But I think it shouldn't be so - the remote ip:port should be still usable to distinguish the packets between the sockets. `connect()` and `bind()` should be denied only if it would result an src_ip:src_port:dst_ip:dst_port collision. Only src_ip:src_port collision shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @peterh The problem is that the API requires that the `bind` succeed or fail before the `connect` call is made, so the implementation doesn't know the remote IP and port when it has to decide whether to permit the assignment of the local IP and port.